# htaccess redirect query is not loading page

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I cannot get this to work. I want

```
http://localhost/test/post.php?id=15
```

to show

```
http://localhost/test/post/15
```

My attempt loads a page without css on it and shows me my customr 404 error page

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^post\.php post/%1? [R,L]
```

please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable for this. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`.

Your code will be:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /post\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ post/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^post/([^/.]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: this worked but all the css is gone. If I chance the path to make it work for this page, it will ruin all the other pages

Comment: For css/js just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: I have my css file in 'test/css/style.css' and the post.php file in 'test' folder, before the htaccess stuff, the css was linked with href="css/style.css" so what should I put now?

Comment: do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: As I commented above your `css` should have link as `href="/test/css/style.css"`

Comment: that worked but some pictures are missing. that means I have to do this everywhere? there is not way to refer it to that style somehow?

Comment: It always better to use absolute URLs but you can try this tag in yor page's `<HEAD>` section: **`<base href="/test/" />`**